# Add header/footer to a file export which uses msSaveOrOpenBlob function

Tags: javascript, html, json, csv, export-to-csv

I have a current implementation which export a report using the navigator.msSaveOrOpenBlob(blob, defaultName) function which takes in only the file data and file name as argument.

Would it be possible to perform a modification to add header/footer information to the blob file using the same function?
Or do I have to look into a different implementation to include the header footer?

Comment: Probably not - blob objects can't be updated although you can combine old and new blobs in a specified order. Note the `msSaveOrOpenBlob` method is deprecated and may stop working at any time, and hence is really only suitable for supporting legacy systems.

Comment: Previous question answers that may be of help:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/24876873/5217142 , https://stackoverflow.com/a/45732897/5217142 , https://stackoverflow.com/q/61203503/5217142 - all assuming the file does not to be rendered in its entirety to add headers and footers.